# Oracle Export Import

Tags: oracle, import, export

I am working for a company that has two Oracle Databases, lets call them LIVE and TEST. An export is performed every night to take a snapshot of the database for each day TEST is then dropped and recreated using existing table creation scripts, with the import finally putting the exported data from LIVE into the new TEST environment.

My questions are,

1. Is this really the best way to do this?
2. What better way is there?
3. Any URL's to demonstrate these ways, would be great

Comment: I have up marked both only allowed to accept one though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Instead of import/export use [Datapump](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Datapump)
2. check [Oracle GoldenGate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index-086263.html)
3. check [Oracle Streams](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/information-management/streams-fov-11g-134280.pdf)

Comment: This answer could be improved if the key tidbits of information pertaining to the links could be extracted. Sometimes links go dead, and always it's better to glean the important bits by an intelligent summary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Enterprise Edition then you can look into transportable tablespaces as well, which have the advantage of exactly preserving the physical state of the data files so performance testing is more realistic.